# How to override translator in symfony 5.2

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to override translator class in Symfony 5.2. I tried this:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ....
    App\Translator:
    decorates: translator
```

and this (App\Translator implements TranslatorInterface):

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ....
    App\Translator:
        arguments:
            $translator: '@translator'

    Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface: '@App\Translator'
```

both methods work well in PHP code, but in development mode in the twig, translator service is still DataCollectorTranslator. So in twig templates the translator service remains not overridden. How can I fix it?

Comment: Based on your posted code you have two App\Translator services defined in services.yaml?  The second definition will override the first.  You should only have the first one which takes care of injecting the original translator into your decorator service.  Also, there is already a TranslatorInterface alias defined so I don't think you need to define one.

Comment: No, these are 2 different attempts to create a decorator. And in both cases, in twig templates in dev mode, the translator service remains not overridden (remains the DataCollectorTranslator).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible I am not understanding the question.  If something works in one mode but not another then sometimes just deleting the var/cache directory and building a new cache with bin/console cache:clear might work.

Decorating services can be a bit interesting sometimes.  I created a fresh 5.2 project and then added:

```
# src/Translation/Translation.php
namespace App\Translation;

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\Pure;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogueInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorBagInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator as BaseTranslator;

class Translator implements TranslatorInterface, TranslatorBagInterface, LocaleAwareInterface
{
    // Uses PHP8 constructor promotion
    public function __construct(private BaseTranslator $translator)
    {
    }
    #[Pure]
    public function trans(string $id, array $parameters = [], string $domain = null, string $locale = null): string
    {
        //return $this->translator->trans($id,$parameters,$domain,$locale);
        return strtoupper($id); // Verify calling this class
    }
    public function getCatalogue(string $locale = null): MessageCatalogueInterface
    {
        return $this->translator->getCatalogue($locale);
    }
    #[Pure]
    public function getLocale(): string
    {
        return $this->translator->getLocale();
    }
    public function setLocale(string $locale)
    {
        $this->translator->setLocale($locale);
    }
}

# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\Translation\Translator:
        decorates: translator

# index.html.twig
<li>{{  'Hello' | trans }}</li>
```

You can disregard the Pure stuff as well as some of the PHP8 stuff.  I was using this as a PHP8 test as well.

But it all seems to work as advertised.

Comment: I don't know what it was. Maybe it was really a cache. Or the end of the working week. You're right. Thanks!